# В какой падеж поставить имя ребенка?

Tags: согласование, падежи, имена

Заполняю документы, и там: «В целях обеспечения моего ребенка Иванову Татьяну (или Ивановой Татьяны?) льготным проездом в автомобильном транспорте и городском наземном электрическом транспорте на территории...».

Answer (score 1):

"В целях обеспечения *моего ребенка*..." —  отвечает на вопросы: "Кого? Чего?" (нет кого или чего — ребёнка) — родительный падеж. Следовательно, верно:

*В целях обеспечения моего ребенка **Ивановой Татьяны** льготным проездом в автомобильном транспорте и городском наземном электрическом транспорте на территории...*

Comment: А запятые не забыли добавить?

Comment: Да вроде нет, уточняющий оборот тут не требуется, можно по аналогии, как советует "Грамота.ру" (см. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=274102).

Comment: *Ребёнок Иванова Татьяна* — так никто не говорит. Да и кто знает, что её ребёнка так зовут? Это же деловой стиль, в таких случаях запятые там всегда ставят. Вне делового стиля запятые иногда опускают, если нет фамилии, у Розенталя как раз такие примеры.